# How could I make my custom view show&disapper like the system keyboard animation in iOS7?

Tags: ios7

I have created a tableview, I wish table view could scroll up/down when keyboard show/disappear.
In iOS6, 
`[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25f animations:^{}];`
works well with keyboard.
So, how could I make my custom view act like the system keyboard animation in iOS7?
Or how to let iOS7 keyboard animation works like iOS 6?

Answer (score 0):

It is a hidden option for animation curve, like you see it when keyboard shows. You can use code below to have the same curve.

NSInteger curve = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue] << 16;

[UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0.0 options:curve animations:^{

} completion:nil];